# Getting group and OU membership information from an endpoint machine

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, saas, directoryservices

Introduction (please forgive me if it's lengthy):
My existing product runs on endpoint computers.
It's written in C# 2.0 (so we're talking about Win OS) and runs under SYSTEM credentials as a service.
I also have a server-side management program that, among other capabilities, displays the organizational domain tree using direct connection with the Directory Provider (either Active Directory or Novell).

However - now I wish to convert to a SaaS model - meaning that the server will not reside on a host inside the organization - so no more direct connection with the directory provider.

In order to still be able to construct the organizational domain tree I decided to solve this problem by adding information about the domain structure to the logs that my clients send.
(If you have a better idea please let me know - although this is not the question yet).

My problem is - how to get the domain info?
I made some attempts with LDAP and DirectoryServices libraries and managed to fetch all the information I need from the DC - but only when a user with sufficient credentials was logged on to the machine...
How can I write a code that runs on an endpoint machine as a service and can (at least) tell the group and OU membership of the machine - and of the logged on user?

Thanks a lot!

[EDIT:] Found something! In the registry, under [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine] - "Distinguished-Name" holds the full LDAP path of the computer. I still need the group membership though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using System.DirectoryServices you can specify a username and password as part of the DirectoryEntry constructor:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("domain ldap path",username, password);
```

If you use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement the constructor for PrincipalContext has options for Domain, user, password.  So you can authenticate as part of your request.

```
PrincipalContext p = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainName, Username, Password);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am familiar with this option but I am trying to avoid storing domain credentials locally (or adding a security exception in the directory provider). This is a last resort.

Comment: @BigDZ - What about setting up a web service in the domain that provides user information but that does not requre authentication.  Then have your org domain tree builder piece use this web service?  We did something like this when we had a page that required anonomous access.

Comment: sorry for the delay (didn't get an email regarding your comment). That's a nice idea which was actually brought up. However - we try to minimize our requirements and footprint. I wonder if I can access the domain information that was stored locally on the machine during its communication with the server. I mean - we can see domain groups in folder permissions and such - so there must be some kind of local cache - no?

Answer (score 0):

Can you set your service to log on as NetworkService?  You should then be able to query the directory, at least.

Comment: I can - but then I have to store domain user credentials locally (for cases when a local user logs in). This is the last resort and I'm still hoping to get an answer that lets me avoid it.